# How to create the custom type for reservation with 30 minutes discrete?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a custom type time range with the 30 minutes discrete.

It's hard for me to write a canonical function without any example.

From documentation:

```
A discrete range is one whose element type has a well-defined "step", 
such as integer or date. In these types two elements can be said to be 
adjacent, when there are no valid values between them. This contrasts 
with continuous ranges, where it's always (or almost always) possible 
to identify other element values between two given values.

A discrete range type should have a canonicalization function that 
is aware of the desired step size for the element type.
```

That custom type time range should have values like:

```
[10:30, 11:00)
[12:00, 14:30)
```

Comment: Huh? What is a "30 minutes discrete"? You'll have to [edit] the question and add **way more** description of your problem.

Comment: What about a `tstzrange` with a check constraint?

Comment: with time zone? As far as I know, I don't need a time zone

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a [discrete range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE) as well (in my case with a step of 1 hour).

As I've found, the [only way to do this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/596023.1611157891%40sss.pgh.pa.us) is to create the [canonical function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DEFINING) as a [C Language function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html).